# i cant change state of setArray. i could change the states of other usestates but not this

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';

import { Paper, Typography, TextField , Button, makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core';

import {useHistory, Link} from 'react-router-dom'

import {useEffect} from 'react';

const Register = () =>{

    const classes = useStyle();
    const history = useHistory();
    const [name, setName] = React.useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');
    const [array, setArray] = React.useState([])

    // useEffect(()=>{
        
    //     const jsonArray = JSON.stringify(arr)
    //     localStorage.setItem('array',jsonArray)
    // },[arr])

    const submit = (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        
        if(array.length === 0){
            const obj = {};
            localStorage.setItem('name', name);
            localStorage.setItem('password',password);
            localStorage.setItem('array',array)
            obj.id = Math.random();
            obj.name = localStorage.getItem('name');
            obj.password = localStorage.getItem('password');
            setName('');
            setPassword('')
            setArray([...array,obj])
            return alert('You are registered'); 
        }
        
       

    }

    return(
        <div>
            <div className = {classes.formWrapper}>
                <Paper elevation={3} className = {classes.paper} >
                <Typography variant="h5" style = {{ textAlign : 'center'}}>Register</Typography>
                <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
                    <TextField id="username" className={classes.textfield} style={{width : '95%'}} value = {name} name = "username"  label="Username" onChange = {e=>setName(e.target.value)} />
                    <br />
                    <TextField id="password" className={classes.textfield} style={{width : '95%'}} value = {password} name = "password"  label="Password" onChange = {e=>setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <Link to='/'>SignIn</Link>
                    <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" style = {{width : '100%'}} onClick = {submit} >Register </Button>
                </form>
                </Paper>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    )
}

export default Register;
```

Comment: Where are you checking array? Cannot see it in the code.

Comment: i'm checking in localstorage in application in inspect

Comment: But the only time you are setting the array value is when array.length === 0. Do you want to set after the array value is updated?

Comment: You have a useEffect for that. Looks like you have a typo with arr and array. Change arr to array. And let us know

Comment: first i checked if the array is empty. it is empty i set states i want to change the state of array by inserting obj in array.

Comment: that useEffect is commented out

Comment: `setArray` is working fine. What's the problem? https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-sun-pp4j6?file=/src/Register.jsx:1042-1061

Comment: It alerts the message fine but it doesnt change state. check localstorage in application in inspect. it gives empty array

Comment: Because you are not setting anything in localStorage. After changing your array using setArray, you have to save in storage too right? Where is that?

Comment: Why have you commented useEffect? That is the piece of code that will help you save in storage?

Comment: i;m storing in localstorage. this localStorage.setItem('array',array)

Comment: But that is before you are setting state right? That time your array is empty.

Comment: yes but in setArray it will update the array. it should insert obj in array but it is not happening